# How to loop numbers.FORMAT_TEXT in Python

Tags: python, excel, text, numbers

Setting cell format to text in excel using Python is a long line of code. At least this has been working fine for me but is there a way I can loop this code so that I won't be copying same line up to 2000 rows. Thank you very much in advance.

```
from openpyxl.styles import numbers
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

ws['F1'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F2'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F3'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F4'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F5'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F6'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F7'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F8'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F9'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F10'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F11'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F12'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F13'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F14'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F15'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F16'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F17'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F18'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F19'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT
ws['F20'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT

wb.save('C:/Test.xlsx')
```

I'm trying to make a loop but I always get below error message. I'm expecting it to be short but same result just like I did.

```
if cell.column_letter == 'F' and cell.row > 1:
```

Results in:

```
AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object has no attribute 'column_letter'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop with format strings like this:

```
from openpyxl.styles import numbers
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for i in range(1, 21):
    ws[f'F{i}'].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT

wb.save('C:/Test.xlsx')
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion however, I got this error message trying the code. for i in range(1, 21):
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: Do you have another variable named `range`?

Comment: Yes, I have another variable named range and I'm using it to loop boarder for 2000 rows.

Comment: Resolved it by renaming the other variable range to range1 :) Thanks for your help.